# MySQL: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES) except root user

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

I am facing problem with mysql non root/admin user, I am following the below steps for creating user and its privileges, correct me if i am doing wrong,

i am installing `mysql` on `RHEL 5.7 64bit`, packages are mentioned below, once i done the `rpm install` we are

1. creating mysql db using `mysql_install_db`, then
2. starting the mysql service then
3. using `mysql_upgrade` also we are doing to the server.

After this process i can login as `root` but with a non-root user I am not able to log into the server:

```
[root@clustertest3 ~]# rpm -qa | grep MySQL
MySQL-client-advanced-5.5.21-1.rhel5
MySQL-server-advanced-5.5.21-1.rhel5


[root@clustertest3 ~]# cat /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[root@clustertest3 ~]# ls -ld /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 Nov  30 11:09 /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

mysql> CREATE USER 'golden'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'golden'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
+----------------+----------------+
| USER()         | CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+----------------+
| root@localhost | root@localhost |
+----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

[root@clustertest3 ~]# mysql -ugolden -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'golden'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

This is the problem I am facing, is there any solution to this?

Comment: Can you login as root and then do ``SELECT * FROM mysql.user``

Comment: Accept the answer that worked for you, so other users know how you solved your problem.

Answer (score 74):

Do not grant all privileges over all databases to a non-root user, it is not safe (and you already have "root" with that role)

```
GRANT <privileges> ON database.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

This statement creates a new user and grants selected privileges to it.
I.E.:

```
GRANT INSERT, SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE ON database.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Take a look at the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-database-privileges) to see all privileges detailed

EDIT: you can look for more info with this query (log in as "root"):

```
select Host, User from mysql.user;
```

To see what happened

Comment: I disagree with that statement about root. Yes you should not give super privileges out willy nilly. However you also generally shouldn't use shared accounts as you have no proper audit trail within the DB. If you must have shared accounts such as root, you require other things wrapped around it to ensure the audit trail is intact.

Answer (score 47):

If you are connecting to the MySQL using remote machine(Example workbench) etc., use following steps to eliminate this error on OS where MySQL is installed

```
mysql -u root -p

CREATE USER '<<username>>'@'%%' IDENTIFIED BY '<<password>>';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO '<<username>>'@'%%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Try logging into the MYSQL instance.
This worked for me to eliminate this error.

Comment: Not even that is working, as it prompts the error even when running "mysql -u root -p"

Answer (score 32):

Try:

```
CREATE USER 'golden'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'golden'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Or even better use: `mysql_setpermission` to create the user

Comment: This does not solve the problem. CREATE USER 'goldy'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass'; is a valid query

Comment: For some reason his ``%`` which should work for all host, isn't solving it. So by specifying ``localhost`` it should work. If that DOESNT work, something is off in mysql

Answer (score 20):

It looks like you're trying to make a user 'golden'@'%' but a different user by the name of 'golden'@'localhost' is getting in the way/has precedence.

Do this command to see the users:

```
SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user;
```

You should see two entries:

1) user= golden, host=%

2) user= golden, host=localhost

Do these Command:

```
DROP User 'golden'@'localhost';
DROP User 'golden'@'%';
```

Restart MySQL Workbench.

Then do your original commands again:

```
CREATE USER 'golden'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'golden'@'%';
```

Then when you go to try to sign in to MySQL, type it in like this:

[image]

Hit 'Test Connection' and enter your password 'password'.

Comment: This is the only solution that I found here that had some significance. Thank you good sir.

Comment: Holy crap, it worked! Nothing else has up until now. Thank you. [solved]

Answer (score 12):

First I created the user using :

```
CREATE user user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password_txt';
```

After Googling and seeing [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-connecting.html), I updated user's password using :

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'user'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password_txt');
```

and I could connect afterward.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who did all the advice but the problem still persists.

**Check for stored procedure and view DEFINERS. Those definers may no longer exists.**

My problem showed up when we changed the wildcard host (%) to IP specific, making the database more secure. Unfortunately there are some views that are still using 'user'@'%' even though 'user'@'172....' is technically correct.

Comment: Thanks for getting me on the right track.  I didn't even know about the SQL Security setting on views and stored procedures.  I ended up setting the SQL Security to Invoker on my views so that it used the permissions of the user executing the command rather than the user who create the view.  Here is a link for reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-security.html

Answer (score 3):

I also have the similar problem, and later on I found it is because I changed my hostname (not `localhost`).

Therefore I get it resolved by specifying the `--host=127.0.0.1`

```
mysql -p mydatabase --host=127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 3):

According way you create your user, MySQL interprets a different manner. For instance, if you create a user like this:

```
create user user01 identified by 'test01';
```

MySQL expects you give some privilege using `grant all on <your_db>.* to user01;`

Don't forget to `flush privileges;`

But, if you create user like that (by passing an IP address), you have to change it to:

```
create user 'user02'@'localhost' identified by 'teste02';
```

so, to give some privileges you have to do that:

```
grant all on <your_db>.* to user02@localhost;
flush privileges;
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the user has a localhost entry in the users table. That was the problem I was having. EX:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Answer (score 2):

For annoying searching getting here after searching for this error message:

> Access denied for user 'someuser@somewhere' (using password: YES)

The issue for me was not enclosing the password in quotes. eg. I needed to use `-p'password'` instead of `-ppassword`

Answer (score 2):

#### Try this:

If you have already created your user, you might have created your user with the wrong password.

So drop that user and create another user by doing this.
To see your current users.

`SELECT Host,User FROM mysql.user;`

To drop the user

`DROP User '<your-username>'@'localhost';`

After this you can create the user again with the correct password

`CREATE USER '<your-username>'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '<correct password>'`;

then

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

You might still run into some more errors with getting access to the database, if you have that error run this.

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to '<your-username>'@'localhost';`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and something dummy ended up solving.
For some reason "locahost" was not resolving for anything, so using its local IP made it work.

So you would change

```
mysql -h localhost -P 33061
```

to:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 33061
```

Answer (score 1):

for cpanel users:
i had this problem and solved it by changing my password in cpanel -> password & security
check the "Synchronize MySQL password" check box while changing your password

Answer (score 0):

In my case the same error happen because I was trying to use mysql by just typing "mysql" instead of "mysql -u root -p"

Answer (score 0):

connect your server from mysqlworkbench and run this command->
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';

Answer (score 0):

The error of `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user` might not be always related to privilages problems but to the fact that there is a **missing `-p` at the end of the command**:

```
# Will prompt us a mysql terminal in case there are no privilages issues
mysql -u root -p 

# Will fail with the mentioned ERROR 1045
mysql -u root
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue when trying to grant privileges to an already existing user using the command:

```
use my-db;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my-database.* TO 'my-user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'my-password';
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

It had to do with 2 issues:

1. The password of the already exiting user was different from the password that provided in the `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` command. I had to rerun the `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` with the correct password for the already existing user.
2. The host name of the database server that I provided when connecting to the database was incorrect. I had created the database and the user on a particular database server and I was trying to connect to another database server different from the database server where the database and the user were created. I had to get the correct database server hostname, and I used it for the connection.

After all this were sorted, I was able to connect to the database using the credentials.

The issue was that `my-user` already had the privileges I wanted to grant it.

You can check to see the privileges that you've granted your user using:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'your-user'@'%';
```

OR

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'your-user'@'localhost';
```

That's all.

Comment: most of the time we add it like 'username'@'localhost' but if the mysql server is not running on your local machine or if it is in a docker container use the ip if not use '%' instead of localhost like 'username'@'%'

Answer (score -1):

sometimes,it can just be a wrong password.Kindly remember your passwords including their sensitivity.

Answer (score -8):

Just add computer name instead of 'localhost' in hostname or MySQL Host address.