# event scheduler won't turn on (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

When I tried this code:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'secret'@'localhost';
```

this is the result:

```
Grants for secret@localhost
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'secret'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'secretpass'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `secret\_dbx`.* TO 'secret'@'localhost'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `secret\_db1x`.* TO 'secret'@'localhost'
```

But when i want to set the event_scheduler on

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = "ON"
```

this error show :

```
 #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

then tried this code :

```
 GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO secret@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'secretpass';
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And then the error:

```
 Access denied for user 'secret'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I know I'm using root , I used the username and password to access the control panel of my domain.

Comment: Try `SELECT USER();`.  What does it return?  You most likely aren't root and don't have sufficient privileges.

Comment: USER()
username@localhost

1 return .. but i got 3 users ....

hmmmm .... and that username@localhost stand for my username in my controlpanel

Comment: Is it possible then that you've granted the SUPER permission to the wrong user?

Comment: checked the other 2 user ... both doesn't have full privileges ....

Answer (score 0):

Check this [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/grant.html). All the permissions are given here.

I think you need to code like:

```
CREATE USER 'secret_user@localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'secret_user@localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

For more information check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353402/access-denied-for-user-testlocalhost-using-password-yes-except-root-user).

Comment: tried that and then error

Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation

Answer (score -2):

found the answer ... and sadly I have to work on cron jobs because i shared a hosting ... now I hate re-seller hosting

Comment: What's the answer you found?