# NodeJS mySQL connection to localhost (NAS)

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection, localhost

I'm creating a NodeJS application running on `localhost:3000`. I'm also trying to make a mySQL connection on my Synology NAS using the following code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '192.168.1.17',
    port     : 3306,
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'password'
});

connection.connect( function(err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log('connected');
});
```

Unfortunately the console keeps displaying an error.

```
ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.15'
```

The strange thing here is that I'm trying to make a connection to my NAS station on `192.168.1.17`, but the console says the host is `.15`. Can someone explain me why?

I've also Googled this issue, but the solution of granting privileges for the root user from [this stack topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353402/access-denied-for-user-testlocalhost-using-password-yes-except-root-user) doesn't seem to work.

Someone can help me out here?

Answer (score 2):

`192.168.1.15` is you, your node app running in your PC, probably you haven't an access list for `root@%` where `%` means from anywhere, you only have access list for `root@localhost` but you aren't on Mysql localhost.

You can add it with this mysql command you have to run on your mysql server:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried it but I'll get the following error: `#1396 - Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%' `. I do suppose I'll have to insert my own password into the identifier? Although I've tried both, but none is working.

Comment: I'm using the SQL tab in phpMyAdmin on my server (localhost).

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed my problem:
It seems that the root user is secured by default.

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'choseAPassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

@Michelem Thanks for the help though ;)