# ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR when connecting to Mysql database

Tags: mysql, connection

***hello***, i am trying to connect to my Mysql database but i get this error : **MySQL error: Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'hulken3'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

I have given this user "hulken3" **all privileges** but it's still not working,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES) except root user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353402/access-denied-for-user-testlocalhost-using-password-yes-except-root-user)

Comment: duplicate? i dont get it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My problem was that my Domain provider was blocking connections to the Mysql database. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to give privilege to new user, so connect as root user and grant permission. Hope information in below site, gives you instruction on how to do that

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html

Comment: okay i will try it out :)