# Yii2 unit testing :: Access denied for user 'something'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: yii2, codeception

When creating automated testing in unit testing. I get this error.

My code is in unit test

```
 function testSavingUser()
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->auth_key='value';
    $user->password_hash='value';
    $user->password_reset_token='value';
    $user->email='value';
    $user->status=1;
    $user->first_name='value';
    $user->last_name='value';
    $user->image='value';
    $user->role_id=1;
    $user->created_date='2016-08-31 16:57:10';
    $user->updated_date='2016-08-31 16:57:10';

    $user->save();
    $this->assertEquals('Miles Davis', $user->getFullName());
    $this->tester->seeInDatabase('users', ['name' => 'Miles', 'surname' => 'Davis']);
}
```

This my config file

```
    $config =  yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/web.php'),
    //require(__DIR__ . '/main-local.php'),
    [
        'id' => 'app-tests',
        'components' => [
            'db' => [
                'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
                'dsn' => 'mysql:host=' . getenv('DB_HOST'). ';dbname=' . getenv('DB_NAME'),
                'username' => getenv('DB_USER'),
                'password' => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
                'charset' => 'utf8',
            ],
        ]        
    ]
);
return $config;
```

In functional.suite.yml

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
    modules:
      enabled:
         - Yii2:
             configFile: 'config/test.php'
```

When trying to execute my test with codecept run it shows error like this

> [yii\db\Exception] SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'something'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Are you sure 'something' user have access for database?

Comment: Yes  i  am sure user have access

Comment: `using password: NO` is a clue that something is wrong with your database parameters

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons of error:

1. Provided credentials are incorrect or mixed with each other. Check them accurately for typos, etc.
2. Environment variables are not accessed or extracted correctly with `getenv` calls. Check if the keys are right and make sure that correct values returned (you can use something like `var_dump`).
3. User has no privileges to access this database. You can see how to set it for example in this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20353578/4323648).