# How to connect to a MySQL server using C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a C# Application which would access a MySQL server on another computer. I am trying to do it via IP. Here is my Connection String :

```
result = "server =66.45.233.226; user id=testcampuscrm; password =Daph$5656; database=testcampuscrm; convert zero datetime=true; ";
```

getting error this

> Access denied for user 'testcampuscrm'@'66.45.232.178' (using
>   password: YES)

My code is anther hosting and mysql database  anther hostig please help us. Thanks

Comment: please provide code snippet you are using

Comment: You have to authorize your machine on the MySQL server. But it's off-topic. You should ask your question on StackExchange or ServerFault. Here is a good start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353402/access-denied-for-user-testlocalhost-using-password-yes-except-root-user

Comment: Please do tell me you haven't just posted the server IP address, username & real password for access to your database.

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple things you have to take into consideration while accessing mysql from another machine some them are -

Assuming you did write correct code

**1.Change mysql config (my.ini) to receive packets from all IP**

**2.Add firewall Exception for port 3306 on machine where Mysql is Hosted**

**3.User name password is Correct and granted proper privileges.**

**PS:-Do not share server credentials on public forums**

Comment: Firewall rule is already there, as the reply comes from the server, demostrating that there is communication. Most likely cause is your point 1 or a wrong password.

Comment: Also worth checking that the User is configured to allow access from the remote IP address.