# SpringBoot 2 use HikariCP can't connect to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

**Phenomenon**

When Sprint Boot project use `application.properties`  as default configure file can connect to MySQL,but when use `application.yml` the project can‘t connect to MySQL.

**Error Message**

```java
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.1' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

**Software Info**

- MySQL 8.0.16

  start command:

```sh
docker run -p 10.70.49.75:3305:3306/tcp -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=0523 mysql
```

- Spring Boot 2.1.5.RELEASE

**Configure**

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://10.70.49.75:3305/jwt?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: 0523
    testWhileIdle: true
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
    hikari:
      idle-timeout: 10000
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
        format_sql: true
        id:
          new_generator_mappings: false
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://10.70.49.75:3305/jwt?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 0523
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**Maven dependency**

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!-- JSON Web Token Support -->
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!-- Starter for using Spring Security -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Is it intentional to have different URLs for yml and properties?

Comment: @ngueno thank you,the jdbc url in yml and properties is same.

Comment: This seems to be related to the MySQL instance. It doesn't allow to you to connect. You must check the MySQL configuration. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353402/access-denied-for-user-testlocalhost-using-password-yes-except-root-user) can be useful

Comment: Put the `0523` in YAML in single quotation marks. Currently it is interpreted as a numeric value, stripping the leading `0` leading to a wrong password. Using `'` will force a string type.

Comment: @M.Deinum  thank you very much,your method solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @M. Deinum,modify the password as one string like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://10.70.49.75:3305/jwt?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: "0523"
```