# "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' : Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

Hi I'm having a problem with laravel 5.3
project was moved from one host to another
and I've updated the `.env` file

The project was working well in the old host
but when I moved to the new host, the site displaying this error

1/2

> PDOException in Connector.php line 119: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'xxxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

2/2

> QueryException in Connection.php line 770: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'xxxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `countries`)

xxxx => The user name for the old database was not updated. i do not know the reason[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwTKg.png)

Comment: does your database has the correct user?

Comment: Looks like a similar issue as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353402/access-denied-for-user-testlocalhost-using-password-yes-except-root-user

Comment: Just a hunch but try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in your `.env` file.  Also try connecting directly via CLI to remove as many factors as possible like old config files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible reasons to throw this exception, let's explore them:

1. There is a kind of cache in the .env file. In this case, you could only rewrite the DB variables, run `php artisan config:clear` and restart the server.
2. Maybe some of the DB variables aren't right. In this case, you could check out the values.
3. The user is right but he hasn't permission to access the database. In this case, you could check out the user permissions.

I hope that one of these tips help you.

Comment: thank you
but the file still does not accept the update with new information
i do not know why

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'xxxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `countries`)



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'xxxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: The project contains different data such as
Username: xxxx
Password: xxxx
Database user name: xxxx
You have changed the old data but the project did not accept the update

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the .env file it should include all value like CONNECTION, HOST, PORT, etc.
2. php artisan config:clear
3. composer dump-autoload and restart the server

Answer (score 0):

the SQLSQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] seems like the password in your .env file doesn't match with the database's password.

You can check the database pass and user in the new server and put into your .env file.

Good luck