# Can't access MySQL in command line through user created in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I'm using Mamp to enter phpMyAdmin, and I created a user. I tried to access MySQL through the command line using: `mysql -u testing -p`, then entering the password. I get `Access denied for user 'testing'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. I also can't access through root. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Answer (score 0):

You must login with `root` user and change `resting` user previlege. your can see this post
[MySQL: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES) except root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353402/mysql-access-denied-for-user-testlocalhost-using-password-yes-except-ro)

Comment: But I also can’t login using root though. I can’t login with any user through the command line.