# wrong host for mysql user using pemelo

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am trying to connect to a mysql database from a asp core net application unsing pemelo.
Here is my connections String:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "WebApiDatabase": "Server=<serverIp>;Port=3306;user='<myUser>';Pwd=<myPw>;Initial Catalog=<database>;"
},
```

I am reciving the error message
`Access denied for user '<myUser>'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

I know whats wrong, it says it is trying to connect from the localhost, but the database is on another maschine.

If I run `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();` in the mysql workbench it shows `'<myUser>@<windowsUserName>', '<myUser>@<Ipaddress>'`. My application should be using one of these.

Funny thing is, if I change the user in my connection String to `<myUser>@<windowsUserName>` then I get the error message `Access denied for user '<myUser>@<windowsUserName>'@'<windowsUserName>' (using password: YES)`. So in this case it does append the correct host name.

I read through the connection string documentation, but I do not understand which rule decides what host he is using. If anybody has a solution, I would appreciate it.

**EDIT**: I am sorry if i formulated the my problem badly.

To clearify it, i only added the @'' to my connection string because I was getting wrong results. My originel connection string is the one I used at the top.

Also i know that the host name in mysql username indicates the host I connect from. That is why I do not understand why it says it is connecting from 'localhost' when i am calling the database from a different pc.

**EDIT 2**:
Somebody asked for Code. So here is the call of the connection string in programm.cs:

```
string verbindungsString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<EtikettenContext>(options =>
        options.UseMySql(verbindungsString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(verbindungsString),
                options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                    maxRetryCount: 5,
                    maxRetryDelay: System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                    errorNumbersToAdd: null))
                .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information)
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors());
```

And here is the full error message.

```
Access denied for user 'etikettUser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 568

   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.ConnectSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, String logMessage, Int32 startTickCount, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 403

   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.ConnectSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, String logMessage, Int32 startTickCount, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 408

   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 98

   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 128

   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(ConnectionPool pool, Int32 startTickCount, Activity activity, Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 929

   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 423

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)

   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlRelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass30_0`2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()

   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IAsyncEnumerableOfTConverter`2.OnWriteResume(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TAsyncEnumerable value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)

   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonCollectionConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)

   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)

   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)

   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCoreAsObject(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)

   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCore[TValue](Utf8JsonWriter writer, TValue& value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, WriteStack& state)

   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultFilters>g__Awaited|28_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)

   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)



HEADERS

=======

Accept: text/plain

Host: localhost:7041

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0

:method: GET

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3

Cookie: PHPSESSID=2tr9dnf5vkacnspngoa54l7qga

Referer: https://localhost:7041/swagger/index.html

TE: trailers

sec-fetch-dest: empty

sec-fetch-mode: cors

sec-fetch-site: same-origin
```

I did not post it the first time, because i think the problem is in the connection string. The connection the the database is there, it is just the user who is not correct.

Comment: That error means you're using the wrong connection string. Most likely you forgot to change the connection string in `appsettings.Production.json`. Pomelo doesn't decide which database to use by itself.

Comment: The host name in mysql username indicates the host you connect **from**, not the host you connect to! Btw this is documented in mysql manual, not in the connection string manual.

Comment: Have you tried using *only* the user name you used to login with MySQL Workbench? The `user` parameter doesn't contain anything beyond the user name. Not the client Windows account, machine or IP. The `Server` contains only the DNS name of the server or its IP

Comment: @Shadow I have edited the question to clearify my problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have edited the question to clearify my problem

Comment: If your hist name is localhost, then you are connecting to a local mysql instance, not to  a remote one.

Comment: I suggest you should  re-check your username and password and try again, also I suggest you could check the user permission to make sure you have the right permissions.

Comment: @Tobias you didn't add any additional information. Pomelo has no bug. `why it says it is connecting from 'localhost'` because your connection string says so. Somehow you're using the wrong connection string. We can't guess what the application code does. Perhaps it uses a hard-coded connection string in `OnConfiguring`? Perhaps there's no `appsettings.Production.json` with the correct server ?

Comment: Post actual code that reproduces the problem. You made a claim that every developer who's worked with either Pomelo or EF Core can disprove. You're asking people to guess what *your* code does

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i added the code that calls the database connection. Also i think you dod not understand that the connection string i posted is the one i am using in my appsettings.json. I just replaced all sensetive Information with placeholders.

Comment: @Shadow It is definetly not a local mysql instance. I am using the IP of another pc in the server field. There is not even a mysql instance running on this pc. Thats why i do not understand why it says it is connecting from localhost.

Comment: @Tobias in that case it's an invalid connection string because `<serverIp>` isn't an IP and  `<myUser>` isn't a valid user name. You posted something like the actual connection string, with missing parts and comments that clearly indicate invalid values were used

Comment: I suspect this is a duplicate of [MySQL: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES) except root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353402/mysql-access-denied-for-user-testlocalhost-using-password-yes-except-ro). The error comes from MySQL itself, not Pomelo

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You might be correct, but none of the solutions i tried there worked for me. Also the fact that he gets the host right when i manually add  `@<hostname>` makes me think that it is at least partially the fault of the application.